# notepad++ zen coding 'wrap with abreviation'

Tags: notepad++, emmet

i am using NP++ and zen coding
when i try to `wrap with abreviation` a word, 
this is the result im looking for:

```
Zynga shares opened <i>slightly<i/> higher Friday
```

but instead, i get this:

```
Zynga shares opened <slightly></slightly> higher Friday
```

i followed instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/Actions#Wrap_with_Abbreviation
any suggestions on why notepad++ is behaving like this and how to fix this?
thank you

re: fixed it with `ctrl+enter` in the abbreviation window.  this is different than `ctrl+e` which is the standard way of executing zen codes

Answer (score 1):

Simply press `ctrl+alt+shift+enter` then type `i`.