# Notepad++: type of line comment (javascript and html) depending on TAG

Tags: javascript, html, comments, notepad++

Notepad++ can toggle line comment with CTRL+Q. But the comment type (using "//", "<--", ";" or whatever) depends on the language of the file.

Is it possible for Notepad++ to comment with "//" only when inside **script** TAG, so that it comments javascript correctly while still using "<--" for all the other html lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notepad++ zen coding 'wrap with abreviation'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658487/notepad-zen-coding-wrap-with-abreviation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that helps.

I use **block comments** for HTML, since it needs opening and closing, and **line comments** for javascript parts inside script tags.

It's not automatic, but not that difficult to see when to use one or another.